# Android - Using swipe left-to-right to go back

Tags: android, android-viewpager, back-stack

I'm a bit new to the Fragments API. I'm building an app that allows the user to navigate up/down through a tree of information. For ease of navigation, I want to allow the user to swipe from left-to-right to navigate back a page.

My initial thought is to try to use the ViewPager and append a new Fragment each time I want to drill-in and automatically remove the last fragment every time the user swipes left-to-right or presses back. I'm having trouble understanding, however, how this interacts with the backstack. Would this behavior be completely separate from the FragmentManager or is there a way to append Fragments to a FragmentPagerAdapter as part of using FragmentManager?